# Turn Off DefaultSettingValueAttribute Create on Application Settings for .Net Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

I have a DLL that accesses a database and reads the connection string from an application setting stored in the config file.  The application that references this DLL will then needs to  set the value for this config setting in its config file.

The problem I'm having is that the generated config code automatically uses my dev connection string as the default value via the `DefaultSettingValueAttribute`.  Then when an application references my DLL it works without creating an entry in its own config file because it is using the default value. This bug wasn't caught until deployment time when the dev connection string was no longer valid.

Is there a way to use the designer for the application settings but turn off the creation of the `DefaultSettingValueAttribute` so that there is no default value and applications are forced to provide a value in the config?

Comment: I'm not sure they'd be "forced" to provide a setting. Have you tried removing it by hand? What happens. It might just make the setting be default(T): null for reference types, 0 for integers, etc.

Comment: I have tried removing by hand, but when you make a new edit to the settings in Project->Properties->Settings then it regenerates the DefaultSettingValueAttribute.

Comment: This also exposes dev settings in the compiled DLL or EXE (if you open the DLL ou EXE in a text editor, try searching for your database username and password)

Answer (score 17):

Pick the entry you want to remove the default value for, and in the Properties window, set `GenerateDefaultValueInCode` to False.

Answer (score -2):

This is late but...

When reading the application settings, use **My.Settings**.TheConfigurationKey instead off **My.MySettings.Default**.TheConfigurationKey